# JSF 1.2: Navigation rules in a different config file

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF 1.2 for my application. I am trying to create a separate config file (named: **navigation-config.xml**) for all the navigation rules throughout my application. Below are the steps I followed for the same:

Made an entry in the `web.xml` file and placed it same directory where the `faces-config.xml` is present:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml,/WEB-INF/navigation-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Below is the content of `navigation-config.xml` :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">

<faces-config>

<navigation-rule>
    <description>Welcome Screen Navigation</description>
    <from-view-id>/login.jspx</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/welcome.jspx</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>      
</navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

When `success`, the navigation is not happening. If I remove the `<navigation-rule>` from the `navigation-config.xml` and add it to my `faces-config.xml` file then the navigation is working perfectly which means there are problems with the `navigation-config.xml` file navigation is having problems.

Please let me know how to resolve this, I need a separate file indicating all the navigation rules.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="1.2"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">` put this on top of the xml file, should work.

Comment: I tried changing it but it is not working. I guess that this should not be a problem, mine is correct only. It seems to have something else though not sure wat is it :(

Comment: With the information you provided, nothing seems to be wrong... :(

Comment: I am also concerned why is it not working. Let me wait for someone else to have a go at it. Please let me know if if you want me to add some additional information on this.

Comment: Try changing `javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES` to `javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES`

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked :(

Comment: @vikas thanks! Changing `javax.faces.application.COMFIG_FILES` to `javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following...

make changes in web.xml file

```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
>     <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
>     <param-value>/WEB-INF/navigation-config.xml</param-value> </context-param>
```